# Pivot table - Display growth rate with calculated field in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a calculated field that displays the growth rate in % from one of the numeric columns in my pivot table.

How can I reference a row above the current cell to calculate the growth rate?

=(Current cell - (Current cell - 1 Row)) / (Current cell - 1 Row)

**Pivot table**

| Year | Count | Calculated Field (YoY Growth) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 100 |  |
| 2020 | 300 | 100% |
| 2021 | 600 | 50% |

[image]

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Referencing to a relative cell is easy, use Offset(Current Cell, -1,0) to go above and so on...  However, using "self" in same formula will get you a Circular Reference warning! If you are 100% certain you need it, then allow circular references for 1 iteration. Yet doing so will prevent further CR warning and might prove more disastrous than helpful.

Comment: @player0 I added the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on instructions:

> =(Current cell - (Current cell - 1 Row)) / Current cell

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B2:B-(B2:B-B1:B999)/B2:B))}
```

[image]

Comment: your example isn't using a "calculated field" in the pivot table.

Comment: See my example on Google Sheets: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tHUiTb249S3Fxjbkapupz4GpsXOZVVWL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @roundrobin try in C2: `={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B3:B-(B3:B-B2:B999)/B3:B))}`

Comment: I messed up the concepts. I didn't know how Arrayformulas work, but know I got the concept. And I don't need an calculated field to make it scale for new rows in my pivot table.

Comment: I don't get it, when using the formula suggested by *player0*, I get an error: _"Circular dependency detected."_ I think it's the same as you have in the screenshot @roundrobin

How did you get this to work?

Comment: @GabrielR. I can check it out if you can share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

I agree with player0, that seeing your sheet, data, data types and layout would facilitate helping you.

However, I'll venture a solution, sight unseen.

There are actually many ways to address what I think you're asking. This is just one of them.

Suppose that your source numbers are in range A2:A. Place the following formula in some other open column, in the cell parallel to the top number in your source range:

`=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({"";FILTER(({A3:A;""}-A2:A)/{A3:A;""},A2:A<>"")},COUNTA(A2:A),1))`

I've added in more "parts" than are probably necessary. But I tried to include controls, seeing as I don't know what your data actually looks like.

An alternative is to place the following simpler formula into the cell *one below* where the top number in your source range is:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,(A3:A - A2:A)/A3:A))`

In either case, you'll want to format the column/range where the results will be as percent (**Format > Number > Percent**).

Obviously, if your source numbers are in a range other than A2:A, you'll need to adjust the ranges in either formula accordingly.

Comment: Hi Erik, I added an screenshot on my question.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just remove the "Calculated Field" from the pivot table and just place my formula alongside the remaining two-column pivot table (in C2 or C3, depending on whether you decide to use my first or second formula, respectively)?

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks so much for your help. Thanks to your help I understood the concept of ArrayFormulas. I was seeking for a solution that didn't require me to keep adding the formula for new rows. I though calculate fields are the solution to this, not knowing that Array formulas allow me this.

Comment: So, did you try my formula as described above? Did it work as intended for you? (In fact, formulas can quite easily produce most pivot tables without the built-in tools; it's just assumed that most people won't invest the time into understanding how to write such formulas themselves.) If this did, in fact, solve your issue, would you take a moment to mark my reply/solution post as "Best Answer"? This allows the contributor community quickly see which issues are fully resolved; and it allows future site visitors to quickly find answers to questions like their own.